# How to convert string list to date and time list

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a string list containing date and time. I want to convert it to date and time list.

```
lstDateTime = [datetime.strptime(x,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f') for x in time]
print("lstDateTime:",lstDateTime)
```

It gives absurd list as
datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 10, 12, 13), datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 10, 12, 14)
while actual string list is like:-
'2017-01-01 16:59:25.000', '2017-01-01 16:59:26.000'

Comment: Could you show example of what you want as an output?

Comment: You could just ask for the string: `lstDateTime = [str(datetime.strptime(x,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')) for x in time]` if you don't want the date object.

Comment: If your code operates on data, you need to include a minimal example of the data and the expected results. Please read [mcre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleanest way is to use pandas, for example with the following `test_list` as strings:

```
import pandas as pd
dates = pd.to_datetime(list, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

This will return a `series` object. In case you need it as list, convert it:

```
lstDateTime = date.to_list()
```

Comment: it's still giving. lstDateTime: [Timestamp('2017-01-01 09:00:00'), Timestamp('2017-01-01 09:00:01'),

Comment: and millisecond is missing

Comment: Because you are converting a string to Timestamp object. the human-readable version of timestamp is what you currently have as a string, also based on your example, `'2017-01-01 16:59:25.000'` has no microseconds. Can you show what are you expecting as the output and maybe the first couple of records?

Comment: it's millisecond not microsecond. But I don't know directive for milliseconds.

Comment: Datetime object in python has no millisecond attribute, nor pandas timestamp object which mimics datetime. In case you want milliseconds, divide by 1k. for example: `test = pd.to_datetime('2017-01-01 16:59:25.123', format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')` and then you can print the milliseconds by `print(test.microsecond//1000)`, for more information check the doc of datetime https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
lstDateTime = [str(datetime.strptime(x,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f').isoformat(timespec='milliseconds')) for x in time]
print(f'lstDateTime: {", ".join(lstDateTime)}')
```

Comment: lstDateTime: 2017-01-01 09:00:00, 2017-01-01 09:00:01,

Comment: millisecond goes missing

Comment: it worked with a small change you missed separator. So it is like this. lstDateTime = [str(datetime.strptime(x,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f').isoformat(sep=' ',timespec='milliseconds')) for x in time]
print(f'lstDateTime: {", ".join(lstDateTime)}')

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the list directly, which causes the objects not to be displayed as formatted strings as you want them to. You can use `strftime()` to get the desired output. If you want to use the same format as the one you used to convert the strings to datetime objects, you can use this:

```
lstDateTime = [datetime.strptime(x,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f') for x in time]
lstDateTime = [x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f') for x in lstDateTime]
print("lstDateTime:",lstDateTime)
```

Comment: Did you execute `from datetime import datetime` before this?

Comment: Ah, I'd missed a quote in the code. Just fixed it. Check it out now.

Comment: it's adding zeroes to make actual millisecond to microsecond. I don't need that. datetime.isoformat() works.